# Does the Reynolds transport theorem still hold if the integrand explicitly depends on the region?

Tags: real-analysis, integration, derivatives

The Reynolds transport theorem states
$$
\frac{d}{dt}\int\limits_{\Omega(t)}f\,dV=\int\limits_{\Omega(t)}\frac{\partial f}{\partial t}\,dV+\int\limits_{\partial\Omega(t)}(\mathbf{v}\cdot\mathbf{n})f\,dA
$$
where

- $\mathbf{v}$ is the derivative of the position of surface element $dA$ w.r.t. $t$ (its velocity, if $t$ is time), and
- $\mathbf{n}$ is the surface normal at $dA$.

I am uncertain if this still holds if $f$ explicitly depends on $\Omega$ (think, just as an example, it is known that $f$ is continuous in $\mathbb{R}^3$ and decays towards the boundary, $f(x)=0$ for all $x\in\partial\Omega$; in that case the second integral would conveniently become zero, but this isn't generally the case). And if it holds, I don't know if $\frac{\partial f}{\partial t}$ should include that dependency or not.

Intuition tells me the answer to both questions is yes. Including both the change of $f$ inside $\Omega$ as well as "the movement of $\partial\Omega$ through a space filled with $f$", roughly speaking, should always capture the full change of the left hand integral. And as long as $\frac{\partial f}{\partial t}$ is known, it should not matter if it originates (fully or in part) from a dependency on $\Omega$ - this is not an optimization problem. (NB: Obviously, if $f$ is discontinuous at $\partial\Omega$, one would have to take the limit approaching from inside $\Omega$ for the last integral.)

But I'm not sure if my intuition is correct here. It would be much appreciated if someone could clarify.